# Get Cell at Row n and Column (by name)

Tags: excel, userform, vba

**System Description:** I have a spreadsheet with a table called *RentLogs* in a spreadsheet (Sheet2, *Renting Logs*). When you click a button, a userform appears and the user selects the date the item was returned and hits "OK". The form then searches the table for the item's ID and logs the check in date in the *Check In Date* column.

[image]

**Problem:**

1) My VBA code (below) can only find the item ID on the whole sheet, how do I find it's location in the table so the table can be moved without worrying about static column values? 
2) How do I get the VBA to drop it in the (item id's row, *Check In Date* column)?

```
Private Sub checkout_cmdbutton_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Renting Logs")

    Const WHAT_TO_FIND As Integer = 200

    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("RentLog").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in (" & FoundCell.Row & "," & FoundCell.Column & ")")
    Else
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found in RentLog")
        Exit Sub
    End If

'copy the check in date to the table
    ws.Cells(FoundCell.Row, ws.Range("RentLog").Column).Value = Me.checkin_datepicker.Value

'clear userform
    Me.checkin_datepicker.Value = Date

'close userform
Unload Me End Sub
```

**My Attempt:** I know the problem lies in my searching algorithm but I'm not familiar with VBA and don't know all the properties of objects. The userform works perfectly so no problem there.

Comment: `ws.Cells(FoundCell.Row, ws.Range("RentLog").Column).Value = Me.checkin_datepicker.Value` looks like your column is using the wrong index, shouldn't it be the `Check In Date`? Maybe I'm not understanding the question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really asking how to refer to cells in a table, you could use something like this. There is a useful guide to syntax here  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

```
Private Sub checkout_cmdbutton_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, r As ListObject, foundcell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Renting Logs")
Set r = ws.ListObjects("RentLogs")
Const WHAT_TO_FIND As Integer = 200

Set foundcell = r.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in (" & foundcell.Row & "," & foundcell.Column & ")")
    r.ListColumns("Check in Date").Range(foundcell.Row - r.HeaderRowRange.Row + 1).Value = Me.checkin_datepicker.Value
Else
    MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found in RentLog")
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

'clear userform
Me.checkin_datepicker.Value = Date

'close userform
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Two errors for my specific version: the table is "RentLog" and the field is "Item ID". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, to refer to a specific column in a table using VBA, you use `Range("TableName[Column Name]")` (actually, this is how you'd refer to it in an Excel formula too: `TableName[Column Name]`).

As for implementation, personally I always go to Index Match.

```
Private Sub checkout_cmdbutton_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Renting Logs")

    Const WHAT_TO_FIND As Integer = 200

    Dim FoundRow As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range, TargetCell As Range

    FoundRow = Application.Match(WHAT_TO_FIND, ws.Range("RentLogs[Item ID]"), 0) ' if there is a match of WHAT_TO_FIND in the "Item ID" column of "RentLogs" table, returns a number corresponding to the row, otherwise returns an error
    If Not IsError(FoundRow) Then ' if there is a match
        Set FoundCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("RentLogs[Item ID]"), FoundRow) ' get the corresponding cell in the "Item ID" column of "RentLogs" table at the same row as the match,
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in (" & FoundCell.Row & "," & FoundCell.Column & ")") ' you may wish to look at FoundCell.Row and FoundCell.Column, as this is currently relative to the worksheet, not the table
    Else ' if there is no match
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found in RentLog")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'copy the check in date to the table
    Set TargetCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("RentLogs[Check In Date]"), FoundRow) ' get the corresponding cell in the "Check In Date" column of "RentLogs" table at the same row as the match
    TargetCell.Value = Me.checkin_datepicker.Value

    'clear userform
    Me.checkin_datepicker.Value = Date

    'close userform
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Getting to `TargetCell`, the above is equivalent to having an excel formula like:

```
=IF(
    NOT(
        ISERROR(
            MATCH(200,RentLogs[Item ID],0)
        )
    ),
    INDEX(RentLogs[Check In Date],
        MATCH(200,RentLogs[Item ID],0)
    ),
    200 & " not found in RentLog"
)
```

Comment: Note: I'd only use `Find` instead of Index Match if I were looking for a partial match. For example, if you had values such as `200`, `1200`, `2001` and you used `Find` for `200`, it would find the first cell that had `200` in it, even if that were `1200` or `2001`.